# How filter JSON files with Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT?

Tags: android, json, android-intent

When I try to open a `.json` file with

```
startActivityForResult(Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
    addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    type = "application/json"
}, 0)
```

the chooser lists files of *all* types instead of just `.json` files. And what's worth, all files are greyed out, I can't select any, **not even** my `.json` files.

However, when I change `application/json` to `*/*`, the files aren't greyed out and I can open them.

With `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` instead of `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` the behaviour is the same.

Why doesn't the type setting work as expected? How to make it work?

Comment: Seems like it is working as intended if you can't select any files except ones that match the type you put into the Intent.

Comment: Am I being trolled here?! Naturally, there were `.json` files among the files I was trying to select. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Android does not support `json` as a MIME type. You can check out the source codes of [MimeUtils](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r48/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java).

```
MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("json");
```

> returns `null`;

You can use `"application/octet-stream"` instead of `"application/json"`
. It will show "*.json files among other files though it will filters out images, videos, music & text files.