# Android default file browser intent showing only *.json files

Tags: android, file

My goal is to list only *.json files in android filebrowser, to load them to the software.

```
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + PATH_TO_WRITE);



    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(folder);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "file/.json");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    Activity activity = (Activity) context;
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
```

Looks like the Android filebrowser dosen't support *.json files. Is there way to implement FileFilter to the intent?

Comment: Incomplete code. Please add to your code how you create your intent as it is unclear what you mean with default file browser.

Comment: `file/.json` is not a [valid MIME type](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).

Comment: Possible duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58055318/how-filter-json-files-with-intent-action-open-document

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using

```
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/json");
```

Edit:

It appears although this currently isn't supported in the default android file explorer (Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14627787/7535148))

Comment: This dosen't work because android does not support "application/json"

Comment: @user257980 It appears that this is correct, this also brings to light another isssue in that on android you can have different file explorers each with their own implementations and intents so there's no guarantee that even if you ask to only show .json files that the file explorer implementation respects your request to do so as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14627787/7535148).

I think a better alternative would be to acount for incorrect files being selected and react accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Sovled this by using custom made file browser because android does not support *.JSON formats. Used this library https://github.com/adityak368/Android-FileBrowser-FilePicker , which was easy to implement